# Can i make graphs in php using SVG? without any 3rd party library or packages?

Tags: php, svg

I had done a API which would take inputs from the users and produce necessary analysis in mathematical way.But i would like to visualize the analysis in graphical form.Can i make graphs in php using SVG? without any 3rd party library or packages?If possible how to make it? I am working on PHP which would take inputs from user and generate the graphs .I had seen many people suggesting to use packages or libraries.I would like to do it by my own .Is it possible? If yes how to start?.

Comment: sure why not.  SVG is just markup, so if you create it via php then boom.

Comment: There are so many excellent libraries for creating SVGs but if you must create your own, start by producing a mockup SVG of what you want the data to look like.

Comment: i had created all the necessary code for analysis in PHP and stored the values in database.But php doesnt have any extension to generate graphs.So i would like to store the values in array and would like to call them in svg or convert them to svg and use them for graph creation.Is this possible?if not can u suggest me the alternate method(without any 3rd party library or extension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it. SVG is a markup language like HTML, so at the most basic level it's just writing a string to a file.  Try opening up an SVG file in a text editor, it can be quite readable if it's just simple shapes.

However, you'll have to learn SVG markup to determine what to put in that file, which would be the bulk of the work. You can find the standard for SVG at https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/.

Comment: cant i just convert the php arrays to xml arrays and use them in svg? to generate shapes?

Comment: SVG is not just XML; it has an expected format, which your data likely doesn't match. You'll need to code something to transform your data into the SVG markup.